# Error/warning while installing any package in R

Tags: r, package, cran

Suddenly I have started getting following error/warning while installing **any package** in R.

```
> utils:::menuInstallPkgs()
Warning: unable to access index for repository     
http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.0
Warning: unable to access index for repository   
http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.0
Error in install.packages(NULL, .libPaths()[1L], dependencies = NA, type = type) : 
no packages were specified
```

I have tried both methods. I have tried downloading binary zip file from http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/index.html for "rjson" package ---> selecting CRAN mirror from menu and then Install package(s)...after this i get aforementioned error.

I have also tried
    install.packages("anypackage")
Now I get the following error

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/ayush/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository   
http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.0
Warning: unable to access index for repository   
http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.0
Warning message:
package ‘rjson’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)
```

I have also tried changing CRAN mirrors. But no luck.

I have also refered to this question earlier asked, [Installation Error When Installing Package from R Forge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287537/installation-error-when-installing-package-from-r-forge) and I have tried the possible solutions mentioned. But not working.

This has started happening suddenly. Earlier I used to download them normally.

I am using latest R 3.0.1. I have also tried switching to earlier versions of R. No luck.

I use windows 7 64 bit. This is happening while installing any package. Please help.

Comment: Kindly help with me this problem. I am not able to do anything.

Comment: What are the results of `traceback()` after this happens?