# Merge "n" rows in a data.frame by taking the sum of each column

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I have a data.frame in R that looks like

```
X1 X2 X3 X4
11  2  3  4
2   5  7  1
12  4  7  6
3   2  9  6
```

I want to sequentially merge every set of two rows into one by taking the sum of their values in each column.

```
X1  X2  X3  X4
13  7   10  5
15  6   16  12
```

Here `13 = 11 + 2`, `7 = 2 + 5`, `10 = 3 + 7` and `5 = 4 + 1`. I have no clue how can I do this in R. Can we use `rbind` or some similar function to achieve this in one or two lines of code?

Comment: `zoo::rollapply(df, 2, by = 2, sum)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can \`ddply\` (or similar) do a sliding window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225992/can-ddply-or-similar-do-a-sliding-window)

Comment: or maybe [this for dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771385/is-there-a-function-like-rollapply-for-data-frame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `split` the dataframe into two groups of alternate rows and then use `Reduce` to add them element wise.

```
Reduce("+", split(df, c(TRUE, FALSE)))

#  X1 X2 X3 X4
#2 13  7 10  5
#4 15  6 16 12
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=10:19)

df[seq(1,nrow(df),2),] + df[seq(2,nrow(df),2),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with base R, which uses the recycling rule and indexing with a logical vector:

```
as.matrix(x)[c(TRUE, FALSE),] + as.matrix(x)[c(FALSE, TRUE),]
```

Testing the code:

```
x <- read.table(head=TRUE, text=
"X1 X2 X3 X4
11  2  3  4
2   5  7  1
12  4  7  6
3   2  9  6")
as.matrix(x)[c(TRUE, FALSE),] + as.matrix(x)[c(FALSE, TRUE),]
#     X1 X2 X3 X4
#[1,] 13  7 10  5
#[2,] 15  6 16 12
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowsum`

```
rowsum(df1, gl(nrow(df1), 2, nrow(df1)))
#  X1 X2 X3 X4
#1 13  7 10  5
#2 15  6 16 12
```